# Brown representability for the standard model category of simplicial sets

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory

Let $Sset$ denote the category of simplicial sets with its Quillen model structure, 
when is a functor $F: (ho Sset)^{op} \to Ab$ representable? With $Ab$ category of Abelian groups. There is probably some classical references but my googlefu wasn't strong enough. I am hoping it would just be the direct translation of Brown representability theorem for $Ab$ valued cofunctors on $hoTop$.

Comment: On second thought I think one can just prove that speculation directly using Quillen equivalence between the two model categories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a second classical paper by Brown himself which abstracts his original paper:

Brown, Edgar H., Jr.
Abstract homotopy theory.
Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 119 1965 79–85.

I think you will find that it applies directly.  Of course, that 
was well before model categories.